# How to refactor so-called constant values, which are read from property files

Tags: java, java-8, constants

I am currently working on refactoring legacy Java code, and found the following coding convention:

```
public class MyClass {
  public static final String CONST_1 = PropertyReader.getProperties("const 1");//PropertyReader will read properties by means of ResourceBundle
  public static final String CONST_2 = PropertyReader.getProperties("const 2");
  //Many similary constant values retrieved from the property file
}
```

The values of `static final String` is retrieved from the property file. My programming instinct give me feeling that this might be an anti-pattern.

**Question: is the coding convention above a very common? If not how can it be refactored to be more readable and maintainable?**

Comment: What's wrong with it? It's the same as `public static final String CONST = "My_Const"`

Comment: That is not true constant as the value can be modified in property file. Really constants is sth like PI, which is always the same value

Comment: The only unclear thing to me is where `PropertyReader` reads properties from. Other things are just fine, and I see no problem.

Comment: What particular issue do you see with it? What's a `PropertyReader`? (I only know of the Android one.) Are you suggesting you'd rather read from whatever it's reading from every time? Please be specific, in the question, about what the concerns are.

Comment: @Rui There are very few "true" constants in programming then. And even then Math.PI isn't a true constant in your eyes. What if you figure out you actually need more than 64 bits of precision for your pi? Constants don't mean it's a number that can never be anything else. It's something that at a minimum should be constant for the entirety of the program. Even if this can be different for different people running it, if it's a main stay in the program then it could be made a constant

Comment: It is absolutely *not* an anti-pattern. Your 'programming instinct' is quite wrong. Somebody has gone to a great deal of trouble to ensure that the values can be modified without having to change the code: and, if it is done correctly, this technique can also enable multilingual applications. Java itself uses this technique extensively. Don't break a working design, especially on a mere whim, and especially when you don't know why it was done that way in the first place and don't appreciate the benefits.

Comment: A variable declared as `static final String` is not necessarily a (compile-time) constant. Your example just has shown that. So why do you assume that something that is not necessarily a constant should be a constant? If the Java designers thought that, it had been easy to eliminate that use case from the language. And well, what alternative do you have in mind?

Comment: @Holger Thanks a lot for you comment :) esp. the first sentence is a good rectification to me. Also it came to my mind for make an *immutable* class called `MyProperties`, which is consisted of all properties, and all `static` method names are just the name of each property, e.g. `header()`, `title()`. At least I feel this way is more object-oriented, how do you think?

Comment: @user207421 Thanks for pointing out my wrong programming instinct :) I also realized so

Comment: @MatthewKerian thanks :) you seem to have the same opinion as Holger :)

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few common ways that people do this:

### Configuration Loader

The pattern that we use in our team is to have a `ConfigurationLoader` which takes in a file. At the beginning of the program, we run `ConfigurationLoader.load()`, which reads the file and populates the various fields. We control reading properties from static getters, which make sure that the `ConfigurationLoader` has already been initialized.

### Static initializer

You can use a static initializer to populate the fields:

```
public static class Constants {
    public static final String string1;

    static {
        string1 = getWhateverConfigString();
    }
}
```

However, I think the way that your codebase already does it is fine, unless PropertyReader is accessing the same file multiple times.

Comment: How is this really different from whatever he's doing? It may be slightly more efficient but that's not really related to what he asked.

Comment: The first option makes it clear that these aren't really *constants* like OP said. Also, it hides the specific implementation of loading the configuration, allowing for error messages, etc.

Comment: That's a fair point

Comment: It doesn't hide anything. It can still be seen. It's just more code. It generates the same bytecode. There is no advantage. And you haven't answered the question.

Comment: @user207421 When I say *hides the implementation*, I don't actually mean that the code is hidden. What I mean is that the user of the configuration loader doesn't **need** to know about the implementation. What does it matter to the user?

Comment: @user207421 and read the last sentence, I have answered the question

Comment: Yeah I'm actually going to bring back my opinion, maybe if you have a ton of variables and you need to declare a config thing or whatever, but outside of that there's no. difference and this would be a pointless refactor